web3py Force transaction to stay pending
A couple of months ago I was looking around Etherscan and saw some accounts that had a pending transaction and when checking its data it'd have a link to the developers telegram.
I thought this was a pretty neat marketing idea since the pending transaction would sit on top of the account transaction list.
Any ideas on how to replicate this on Python? I just need guidance since I've no clue on how to make the transaction stay pending.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
